# How can i disable datepicker from sharepoint list date column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, datepicker

In sharepoint when we edit a list having a date column date picker is available.Is there any way i can disable, hide or remove that date picker.

Comment: So, you wanna hide the date column? Are you using it or do you just wanna get rid of it?

Comment: Or do you want a date-formatted column that doesn't have a picker control?  And which version of SharePoint?

Comment: Yes i want the date column to be readonly.i am able to make the textarea of date field readonly through javascript.but the datepicker is causing problem.

Comment: I am using sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 3):

```
// Set text input to readOnly   
$( "td.ms-dtinput > input[id$='DateTimeFieldDate']" ).attr('readonly', 'readonly');

// Disable to onclick action on the button
$( "td.ms-dtinput > a" ).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');

// Disable the 2 select elements
$( "td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateHours']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$( "td.ms-dttimeinput > select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']" ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Original answer from:
[How to make datepicker readonly from javascript?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82596/how-to-make-datepicker-readonly-from-javascript)

Comment: Jquery doesnot seem to work for me.

Comment: try this following: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81f51702-fe9e-4d0b-99c3-80fdbc55680a/sharepoint-2007-list-datepicker?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: <script language="javascript">
$(function(){
  $('a[onclick*="clickDatePicker"]').css('display','none');
});
</script> I am able to hide the datepicker from all the datetime fields using the above code.But I want to hide the datepicker from one datetime field only.Any solution?

Comment: is that mean that you have multi date picker control but you want to specific hide one date picker field. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
This code worked for me.
 <script type="text/javascript">
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hidecal");
 function hidecal()
 {
  document.getElementById('id of the cal image').style.visibility='hidden';
 }
  </script>
```