# How to hide the calendar image for a particular group

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-calendar, datepicker

I need to make a column date read only for a particular group in SharePoint. I am able to make the textarea of date field in `editform.aspx` readonly.

I have a content editor where I am using JavaScript to hide the date field and I have set the target audience to that group. But the datepicker is causing problems. So I need some code that can hide the calendar image or disable the datepicker for that particular group.

I have tried many pieces of code, but jQuery does not seem to work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i disable datepicker from sharepoint list date column](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103978/how-can-i-disable-datepicker-from-sharepoint-list-date-column)

Comment: It does not look like a duplicate to me

Comment: By default you hide the fields you want, and you use a Content Editor that only appears for a specific group, and inside this Content Editor you use some JavaScript to unhide the fields you want...

Comment: I only want the calendar icon of the particular date column to be disabled or hidden.i have code that hides all the calendar image of the form which i don't want.