# How to disable the datepicker image click?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a 3 date picker fields. I have disabled the field but the date picker icon is fully functioned. Can any one tell me how to disable it's function?

Answer (score 1):

To hide the datepicker image use css,

`<style>
.ms-dtinput > a {
display: none;
}
</style>`

**Update**

Using pure JavaScript

`<script type="text/javascript">
function clickDatePicker()
{
document.getElementsByTagName('a').onclick = null;
}
</script>`

This will disable all date pickers on the page. I tested on item edit page with Script editor webpart.

Comment: thank you,i don't want to hide but disable it

Comment: you welcome!. I updated my answer. Tested on my test environment.

Comment: I don't want to disable all...only 2 out of 3 should be disabled

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(“input[title$=’ShowFields’]”).click(function()//metion field names that you need to be in your form 
{

$(“input[title$=’datepicker1’]”).parent(‘span’).parent(‘td’).parent(‘tr’).toggle();//mention the field names that you need to hide or disable from your form 
$(“input[title$=’datepicker2’]”).parent(‘span’).parent(‘td’).parent(‘tr’).toggle();//mention the field names that you need to hide or disable from your form
$(“input[title$=’datepicker3’]”).parent(‘span’).parent(‘td’).parent(‘tr’).toggle();//mention the field names that you need to hide or disable from your form

});

});
</script>
```

try this too

[How to make datepicker readonly from javascript?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82596/how-to-make-datepicker-readonly-from-javascript)

try this too

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() {   
$( "td.ms-dtinput > input[id$='DateTimeFieldDate']" ).attr('readonly', 'readonly');    
$( "td.ms-dtinput > a" ).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');   });  
 </script>
```

Comment: It's not working.The date picker functionality is still not disabled

Comment: did you tried below-posted URL ..?(How to make datepicker read-only from javascript?)

Comment: It disables all date fields. I want to disable specific fields

Comment: replace  id$='DateTimeFieldDate' with title$=’datepicker title’                                 $( "td.ms-dtinput > input[title$=’datepicker title’ ]" ).attr('readonly', 'readonly');

Comment: Then also it's not working :(